# what to add to or remove from to change lines

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm a beginner in learning actionscript and i'm seeing examples to learn from them. in the following lines, what should i add or remove so i can hide or not show system messages?  and what are these lines actually say?

```js
 public function set showSystemMsgs(param1:Boolean) : void
        {
            var _loc:* = this.showSystemMsgs;
            if (_loc !== param1)
            {
                this.showSystemMsgs = param1;
                this.dispatchEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(this, "showSystemMsgs", _loc, param1));
            }
            return;
        }

        public function get showSystemMsgs() : Boolean
        {
            return this.showSystemMsgs;
        }

        public function removeEventListener(param1:String, param2:Function, param3:Boolean = false) : void
        {
            _bindingEventDispatcher.removeEventListener(param1, param2, param3);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to understand code, stop reading decompiled code. This is not code meant to be read by humans opposed to what the code looked like before compilation.

There are plenty of resources on pretty much everything available by now, with explanations, comments and readable code.

```
object.showSystemMsgs = false;
```

Might work, where object is a reference to an object of the class which you partially posted.